# Type Error: cannot read property length of undefined for empty_value_check

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django

These are the javascript functions for my html form, to validate for empty values in "input" elements and "select" elements respectively. The empty_select_check function doesn't work and I'm not sure why, but the empty_value check works for the individual fields. However, it does not work in the empty_value_all() fucntion. Note that the empty_value_all() is called when the user clicks submit.
I get the following error:

Type Error: cannot read property length of undefined for empty_value_check. Any idea why it works for individual fields but not for when i try to submit? Let me know if you require my html code but basically its just input elements with an onkeyup="" where I call the js functions.

```
  function submitform(){
      empty_value_all()
      $('#Start').click()
    }
  }


function empty_value_check(ele) {
  let value = ele.value;
  console.log(value)
  if (value === '' || value.length === 0) {
    if ($(ele).closest('div').find('small').length != 0)
      $(ele).closest('div').find('small').removeClass('hide').removeClass('d-none');
    else
      $(ele).closest('div').nextAll('small').removeClass('hide').removeClass('d-none');
      $(ele).addClass('is-invalid');
  }
  else {
    $(ele).nextAll('small').addClass('hide');
    $(ele).removeClass('is-invalid');
  }
}


function empty_select_check(ele) {
  if (ele.value === "Select Folder" || ele.value === undefined) {
      $(ele).addClass('invalid-feedback');
  return false
    } else {
      $(ele).removeClass('is-invalid');
    }
}


$(function() {
  $('#field_5,#field_6,#field_7').on('change', empty_select_check(this))
})

function empty_value_all() {
  $('#field_1,#field_2,#field_3,#field_4').each(empty_value_check(this));
  $('#field_5,#field_6,#field_7').each(empty_select_check(this));
  return false;
}
```

Comment: looks like the parameter you are passing into the `empty_value_check` is not being processed correctly, since this is a `TypeError` and your function expects a string then you have to find out it gets an `undefined` type object

Answer (score 0):

`$(selector).each(looping_function)` expects a function as input, but in the code in question, it is the result of the function that is being passed. Update `empty_value_all` as below and try,

```js
function empty_value_all() {
    $('#field_1,#field_2,#field_3,#field_4').each(function () {
        empty_value_check(this);
    });
    $('#field_5,#field_6,#field_7').each(function () {
        empty_select_check(this);
    });

    //...

}
```